# Recursion for erlang not working. Getting function clause matching error

Tags: recursion, erlang

So I'm getting problems with my recursion. I'm getting a function clause matching error. The recursion stops when each student receives the same number of candy pieces. I'm sure I did the recursion exit conditions right. What's wrong?

```
-module(assignment3). 
-export([main/0, students/4, givecandy/4, teachergivecandy/4]).

main() ->
    io:fwrite("Hello\n"),
    students(4, 2, 2, 1). %Define how many candy each students get

givecandy(Student1, Student2, Student3, Turn) when (Student1 == Student2) and (Student2 == Student3) -> 1;
% recursivecandy(Student1, Student2, Student3, Turn) when (Student1 /= Student2) and (Student2 /= Student3) -> givecandy().

givecandy(Student1, Student2, Student3, Turn) when (Student1 /= Student2) and (Student2 /= Student3) ->
    io:format("Turn123"),
    Student1Total = (Student1 div 2) + (Student3 div 2),
    Student2Total = (Student2 div 2) + (Student1 div 2),
    Student3Total = (Student3 div 2) + (Student2 div 2),
    TurnCount = Turn + 1,
    teachergivecandy(Student1Total, Student2Total, Student3Total, TurnCount).

students(X, Y, Z, Turn) ->
    Student1 = X,
    Student2 = Y,
    Student3 = Z,
    TurnCount = Turn,
    io:format("Turn: ~p~n" , [TurnCount]),
    io:format("Student 1 Total: ~p~n" , [Student1]),
    io:format("Student 2 Total: ~p~n" , [Student2]),
    io:format("Student 3 Total: ~p~n" , [Student3]),
    givecandy(Student1, Student2, Student3, TurnCount).

teachergivecandy(Student1Total, Student2Total, Student3Total, TurnCount) ->
    io:format("hello1"),
    if 
        Student1Total rem 2 == 1 -> 
            Student1FinalTotal = Student1Total + 1; %Student1FinalTotal = Student1Total + 1,
        true ->
            Student1FinalTotal = Student1Total
    end,
    if 
        Student2Total rem 2 == 1 -> 
            Student2FinalTotal = Student2Total + 1; %Student1FinalTotal = Student1Total + 1,
        true ->
            Student2FinalTotal = Student2Total
    end,
    if 
        Student3Total rem 2 == 1 -> 
            Student3FinalTotal = Student3Total + 1; %Student1FinalTotal = Student1Total + 1,
        true ->
            Student3FinalTotal = Student3Total
    end,
    io:format("Student 1 Total: ~p~n" , [Student1FinalTotal]),
    io:format("Student 2 Total: ~p~n" , [Student2FinalTotal]),
    io:format("Student 3 Total: ~p~n" , [Student3FinalTotal]),
    io:format("Turn: ~p~n" , [TurnCount]),
    givecandy(Student1FinalTotal, Student2FinalTotal, Student3FinalTotal, TurnCount).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `givecandy/4` got no function clause matching. It seems that you want to check all 3 students have the same candy or not, so you can change like below:

```
givecandy(Student1, Student1, Student1, _Turn) -> 1;
givecandy(Student1, Student2, Student3, Turn) ->
    io:format("Turn123"),
    Student1Total = (Student1 div 2) + (Student3 div 2),
    Student2Total = (Student2 div 2) + (Student1 div 2),
    Student3Total = (Student3 div 2) + (Student2 div 2),
    TurnCount = Turn + 1,
    teachergivecandy(Student1Total, Student2Total, Student3Total, TurnCount).
```

The result in shell:

```
1>assignment3:main().
Hello
Turn: 1
Student 1 Total: 4
Student 2 Total: 2
Student 3 Total: 2
Turn123hello1Student 1 Total: 4
Student 2 Total: 4
Student 3 Total: 2
Turn: 2
Turn123hello1Student 1 Total: 4
Student 2 Total: 4
Student 3 Total: 4
Turn: 3
1
```

I have small code to solve this issue below:

```
-module(foo).
-compile(export_all).

start()->
    io:format("A   B   C   Turns~n"),
    d(4, 2, 2, 0).
d(_A, _A, _A, B) ->
    io:format("~p   ~p   ~p   ~p~n",[_A, _A, _A, B]);
d(A, B, C, D)->
    io:format("~p   ~p   ~p   ~p~n", [A, B, C, D]),
    Na = check(A, B),
    Nb = check(B, C),
    Nc = check(C, A),
    d(Na, Nb, Nc, D + 1).

even(X) when X >= 0 -> (X band 1) == 0.
check(A, B)->
    N = trunc((A + B)/2),
    case even(N) of
        true -> N;
        false -> N + 1
    end.
```

The result in shell:

```
> foo:start().
A   B   C   Turns
4   2   2   0
4   2   4   1
4   4   4   2
ok
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two clauses for `givecandy` with guard conditions `(Student1 == Student2) and (Student2 == Student3)` and `(Student1 /= Student2) and (Student2 /= Student3)`. But it can be that both guards fail, e.g. `givecandy(1,2,2)`.

Probably one of recursive calls ends up looking like that ("probably" because you don't include the error message in the question, and it should say exactly what function and arguments are the problem). So you need to add another clause to handle this case or to change the guards.

It's good practice for the last clause to have no guards so it can handle all missing cases. Of course, it might just be to throw an exception if there's nothing better to do!